# Key - Values with JQuery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery

Is the standard JQuery autocomplete able to get key-values instead of only keys or only values.

Forexample userIds and username.

```
1 - Roel Veldhuizen
2 - Pino Jansen
3 - Afred van Buren
```

Where the userId is the saved value but the username is the search value and the value which is showed to the user.

Current code:

```
<script>
                    <!--
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#creatorUserId").autocomplete("Gateway.php?action=UserAction&subAction=suggest");
                    });
                    -->
                    </script>           
<input type="text" name="creatorUserId" id="creatorUserId" value="3" size="40" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Check example on the offisial site: [Remote JSONP datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp).

There you can find that JS objects are binded to autcomplete and you can use any property of this object. In your case you need to format objects with name and value and use value when you need.